# Python - scraping a paginated site and writing the results to a file

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a complete programming beginner, so please forgive me if I am not able to express my problem very well. I am trying to write a script that will look through a series of pages of news and will record the article titles and their links. I have managed to get that done for the first page, the problem is getting the content of the subsequent pages. By searching in stackoverflow, I think I managed to find a solution that will make the script access more than one URL BUT it seems to be overwriting the content extracted from each page it accesses so I always end up with the same number of recorded articles in the file. Something that might help: I know that URLs follow the following model: "/ultimas/?page=1", "/ultimas/?page=2", etc. and it appears to be using AJAX to request new articles

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import urllib
r = base_url = "http://agenciabrasil.ebc.com.br/"
program_url = base_url + "/ultimas/?page="

for page in range(1, 4):
    url =  "%s%d" % (program_url, page)
    soup = Soup(urllib.urlopen(url))



letters = soup.find_all("div", class_="titulo-noticia")

letters[0]

lobbying = {}
for element in letters:
    lobbying[element.a.get_text()] = {}

letters[0].a["href"]
prefix = "http://agenciabrasil.ebc.com.br"

for element in letters:
    lobbying[element.a.get_text()]["link"] = prefix + element.a["href"]



for item in lobbying.keys():
    print item + ": " + "\n\t" + "link: " + lobbying[item]["link"] + "\n\t"

import os, csv
os.chdir("...")

with open("lobbying.csv", "w") as toWrite:
    writer = csv.writer(toWrite, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(["name", "link",])
    for a in lobbying.keys():
        writer.writerow([a.encode("utf-8"), lobbying[a]["link"]])

        import json

with open("lobbying.json", "w") as writeJSON:
    json.dump(lobbying, writeJSON)

print "Fim"
```

Any help on how I might go about adding the content of each page to the final file would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It might also be a good idea to take a look at a tool like [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)

Comment: My issue was solved by another poster but I'll look into that anyway, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the code in your for loop (`for page in range(1, 4):`) isn't been called due to your file not been correctly indented:

If you tidy up your code, it works:

```
import csv, requests, os, json, urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

r = base_url = "http://agenciabrasil.ebc.com.br/"
program_url = base_url + "/ultimas/?page="

for page in range(1, 4):
    url =  "%s%d" % (program_url, page)
    soup = Soup(urllib.urlopen(url))



    letters = soup.find_all("div", class_="titulo-noticia")

    lobbying = {}
    for element in letters:
        lobbying[element.a.get_text()] = {}

    prefix = "http://agenciabrasil.ebc.com.br"

    for element in letters:
        lobbying[element.a.get_text()]["link"] = prefix + element.a["href"]



    for item in lobbying.keys():
        print item + ": " + "\n\t" + "link: " + lobbying[item]["link"] + "\n\t"

#os.chdir("...")

with open("lobbying.csv", "w") as toWrite:
    writer = csv.writer(toWrite, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(["name", "link",])
    for a in lobbying.keys():
        writer.writerow([a.encode("utf-8"), lobbying[a]["link"]])


with open("lobbying.json", "w") as writeJSON:
    json.dump(lobbying, writeJSON)

print "Fim"
```

Comment: Man, thank you so much, it works just like I wanted it to. I am still getting used to how disciplined you have to be when coding.

Comment: Practice makes perfect! Python is a great language for scraping. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

How about this one if serving the same purpose:

```
import csv, requests
from lxml import html

base_url = "http://agenciabrasil.ebc.com.br"
program_url = base_url + "/ultimas/?page={0}"
outfile = open('scraped_data.csv', 'w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Caption","Link"])
for url in [program_url.format(page) for page in range(1, 4)]:
    response = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    for title in tree.xpath("//div[@class='noticia']"):
        caption = title.xpath('.//span[@class="field-content"]/a/text()')[0]
        policy = title.xpath('.//span[@class="field-content"]/a/@href')[0] 
        writer.writerow([caption , base_url + policy])
```

Comment: Oh, I ended up making several modifications to this script, to the point that it is mostly unrecognisable today. But thanks for the input! Your approach seems to be more efficient, indeed. I will try it out later.